# Unexpected behavior of g++ -MG flag

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

I have `main.cpp` file for which I want to generate dependency file `main.d` (to be included in `Makefile`).

I'm calling `g++ -MM -MF src/main.d -MP -MT src/main.o src/main.cpp`. It works fine unless I have some source generator. I found `-MG` flag for this, but it doesn't work as I expected it to work.

For example: `main.cpp` includes `module/mod.h` (`#include "module/mod.h"`) and `mod.h` includes `generator/gen.h` (`#include "generator/gen.h"`), `gen.h` is generated. There is following structure:

```
-Makefile
-src
--main.cpp
--module
---mod.h
---generator
----gen.h
```

In `Makefile` I have a rule to generate `src/module/generator/gen.h`.

Generated by `g++` dependencies for existing files are correct:

```
src/main.o: src/module/mod.h
```

But for non-existing file `gen.h` dependency is just `generator/gen.h`.

If I generate this file before generating dependencies it is correct `src/module/generator/gen.h`.

Is there any other option for `g++` to correctly generate dependencies for non-existing files?

`main.d` generated when `gen.h` doesn't exist:

```
src/main.o: src/module/mod.h generator/gen.h
```

Correct `main.d` generated when `gen.h` exist:

```
src/main.o: src/module/mod.h src/module/generator/gen.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in man gcc

> The dependency filename is taken directly from the "#include" directive without prepending path

actually there's no way for gcc to know the real path.
I'd recommend you to fix the include statement to keep include path in sync with make path, i.e. white in `mod.h`

```
#include <module/generator/gen.h>
```

put `Makefile` to `src` and add proper -I flag to gcc, e.g.

```
SRCDIR := $(shell pwd)
CXXFLAGS += -I$(SRCDIR)
```

it is a good practice to always start all non-local includes from some 'source root'

Comment: Why there is no way to know the real path? If in file from directory "a/b/c" is `#include "d/e.h"` file `e.h` is in `a/b/c/d/e` directory? So it is pretty easy to determine full path for `""` include.

Comment: thats becaus of -I (or -iquote) switches -- you can have 10 directories to be scanned for include file and unless file exists it's not possible to say for sure

Comment: I'd recommend you to try cmake. I dont like it but it solves this particular problem - you'll provide the name explicitly threre

Comment: OK, I always thought that -I is for <...> includes.

Comment: Just to clarify subtleties of <..> and ".." for history -- both <...> and "..." search paths are set with -I, while only "..." search path is set by rarely met -iquote. <..> include system include folders (like /usr/include) while ".." includes directory where including source file resides